# How do I fix the "The shadow-piercing descendant combinator (>>>) is deprecated" warning on ng build for production

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm getting ng-build -c production warnings for all my css in styles that have a '>>>' notation.

> Warning: ▲ [WARNING] Unexpected ">" /Users/mike/project2022/client/src/app/bank/bank-new/bank-new.component.ts-angular-inline--13.css:33:13:
> 33 │       :host >>> .nav-item > a {

**QUESTION** - How do I fix this?

ex. '>>>' giving warnings on build

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bank-new',
  templateUrl: './bank-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bank-new.component.scss'],
  styles: [
    `
    :host >>> .nav-item > a {
      color: #17a2b8 !important;
    }
    :host >>> form-wizard > .card {
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      height: calc(100vh - 57px) !important;
      border: none !important;
    }
    :host >>> .card-footer {
      display: none !important;
    }
    `
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep :

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator (>>>) is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

So your best bet would be to remove / replace all your >>> selectors with non shadow-piercing descendant combinator alternatives. The linked [support is being removed from major browsers](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6750456638341120) might help in finding alternatives.

You could also try if the ::ng-deep alternative works and does not throw warnings.

Comment: So I replace >>> with ::ng-deep ? What are "non shadow-piercing descendant combinator alternatives" ?

Comment: **Q:** What are "non shadow-piercing descendant combinator alternatives" ?
**A:** Selectors / rules that provide the same result _without_ using `:host >>>`. Looking at the linked https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/blink-dev/HX5Y8Ykr5Ns/discussion , you could try the suggested replacement " " (the standard descendant combinator).

**Q:** So I replace >>> with ::ng-deep?
**A:* You can try. Not sure though if it will work as ::ng-deep is long deprecated, too.

Comment: So what do I replace ::ng-deep with?